# Lambda function timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-vpc

I have a Lambda function (initiated by API Gateway) that accesses an Aurora Cluster in private subnets (no errors in CloudWatch, just that the function timed out).

If I invoke the function several times, at around 5 concurrent executions it is timing out and returning 502 errors from API Gateway.

I know there can be issues with cold start times when accessing a VPC, due to ENI's being created, and I need to make sure to have enough IP's for the ENI's to be created. But using the formula from AWS (my function has 512MB, and the private subnets has a /24 range, meaning 254 usable IP's):

`IP's for ENI's = Projected peak concurrent executions * (Memory in GB / 3GB)`

`254 = Projected peak concurrent executions * (512/3000)`

`Projected peak concurrent executions = 1400+`

Way higher than ~5. Have I missed something? Do I somehow need to manually create the ENI's, or is making sure I have enough available IP's enough?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that Lambda actually times out? Meaning that Lambda waits for some external resource forever? Or just hang there because of an unhandled exception of some sort?

Comment: Thanks for replying! No it can’t be that, I refresh my site rapidly about 10 times, works fine 9 times, then fails. It’s definitely something to do with the load.